# Photoshop - Resizing shape's layer style

Tags: photoshop

I'm working on some icon made from shapes and for each shape i used a layer style.
When i enlarge the icon with the "Free Transform Path" some of the effects in the layer style won't scale accordingly and will look different.
Is there any way to scale the icon without lossing the effects?

Comment: As this question does not relate to programming, but rather general software usage, it would be better suited to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge down layers as one layer, then try enlarging the shape.